# CSS not Loading in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having a problem with my magento, CSS is not loading.. and when I take a look on its source. There's a problem with my path..

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mycommerce_comhttp://mycommerce.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css" media="all" /
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mycommerce_com is not supposedly in the path.

the correct path must only: http://mycommerce.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css

Whats the solution for this? I already did all the solution given by google.

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

can you check under System => Configuration => Web, under both Secured and Unsecured tab the value of skin folder, if you website is running correctly then I assume you have your base URL correct. If so then the value for media and skin should just be:

```
{{secure_base_url}}skin/
{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
```

Comment: also if you familiar with Magento EAV, each setting has different scopes. So you might want to check the website and store scope as well

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the controlcentre
System =>   Configuration   =>  Web

The main point to watch out for is

i.  Url options  ->  Add store code to Urls should be 'No'

ii.  Unsecure  ->  Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

iii. Secure  ->  Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

also you should have

{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

for your Base Skin